# Getting filtered data from many to many relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent, many-to-many

I need to get filtered data from many to many relationship  from Post and Tag tables.

I have Post Model:

```
class Post extends Model
{
    public function tag()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Tag', 'post_tag','post_id','tag_id');
    }   
}
```

And Tag Model like:

```
Class Tag extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['name'];

    public function post()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Post::class, 'post_tag');
    }  
}
```

But when I try to get filtered data based on tag_id:

```
if($request->filled('tag_id')){
           $posts = Post::whereHas(
               ['tag' => function($query) use($request)
                   {
                       $query->where('tag_id','=', $request->input('tag_id'));
                   }
               ])->get();
       }
```

It doesnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to [laravel doc](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence)

whereHas take string and callback function as parameters not an array:

```
 $posts = Post::whereHas(
               'tag' ,function($query) use($request)
                   {
                       $query->where('tag_id','=', $request->input('tag_id'));
                   }
               )->get();
```

Comment: You can accept an answer in 3 minutes  :) So after 3 minutes i will do it